# I'm trying to add numbers to each new line

Tags: c, loops, rectangles

I am trying to print out a sequence of numbers and `*` that form a rectangle depending on the number provided by the user. I managed to print a rectangle with `*` but I do not know how to incorporate numbers to print out something like:

```
1*****
12****
123***
1234**
12345*
123456
```

This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main{
    int i, j; 
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number from 1-9: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for(i=1; i<=num; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=num; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you supposed to output if the user is unkind enough to enter 12? (Oh, you say "enter a number 1-9" but you don't check that's what they entered.) You need a loop to print digits and a loop to print stars, and then output the newline.  Within the outer `for` loop, you need two consecutive inner loops (or you can use conditional printing if you prefer, but it probably isn't as clear.

Comment: Suppose you replace `printf("*")` with `printf("%d", j)`, does this give you any clues?

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this helps!**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int i, j;
int num;

    printf("Enter a number from 1-9: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for(i=1; i<=num; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            printf("%d",j);
        }
        for(;j<=num;j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also,Instead for using 2 loops inside of Master loop,You can Use conditional operators to manipulate output!
*Cheers! :)*

Comment: Are you sure that providing a homework solution is really helping?

Comment: I just tried to help someone whose maybe new to programming so that he/she can learn more. It just took me like 30 secs to modify that code.